# Way to change info.plist value without giving new build

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, info.plist

I have a function who is getting Base Url from info.plist's configuration key. I forgot to change that to **Production** and was in **Staging** state at the time of generating my build and now it is using development base url.

So is there any way to change that without giving a new build as it is very small change and for one thing i don't wish to publish a new build. I know it is not possible but still if anyone have any other solution, would be great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your info.plist is part of the signed bundle. To change it you need to create a new build.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that comes in my mind, you can make a 301-redirect from your stage to production.

Comment: Can we forward the request objects too at the time of redirecting api ?

Comment: if you use something standard iOS libraries and standard HTTP then yes, request data is also transferring to new location